# catch all unused sub domains not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

im using wildcard subdomains and would like to specify the directory to send an unused subdomain.
i have edited the 000-default in my sites enabled but that does not effect anything.

how could i track down where the setting are for the unused?

Im running ubunutu 10.04.

Comment: What's the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Ubuntu don't ship `apachectl` (or, at least, the 10.04.3 LTS I have access to doesn't have one). You (somewhat-annoyingly) need to substitute what-I-put-in-my-answer.

Comment: @nickgrim Should be `apache2ctl`, then?

Comment: Ha! Yeah, that works too.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Requests will be going to the first `VirtualHost` that has either a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` that matches the requested hostname (including wildcards like `*.example.com`). If you don't have any matches, they'll be going to the first-defined `VirtualHost`.

Since editing `000-default` hasn't made any difference, I presume you've got a more-specific `VirtualHost` somewhere.

```
grep -r example.com /etc/apache/
```

should help you find the file it's in (obviously, replace `example.com` as necessary).

Also, you can do the following to see a list of all your `VirtualHost`s:

```
APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data /usr/sbin/apache2 -S
```

(EDIT: or, indeed, just `apache2ctl -S`)

Comment: thanks! i was able to find out the the default domain is pointing to var/www (plesk .. grrr)
grepping the default servername in apapche2/ didnt show anything...
so maybe its a plesk thing, but where could the conf be that routes default. i should mention the default is a server id subdomain. (rs2353.host.com)